# How to determine if Expression<Func<T, object>> is valid for EntityFramework .Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I have a method for retrieving an entity using EntityFramework that accepts an array of the Navigation Properties that should be included:

```
public virtual T GetSingle(Guid id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    T item = null;

    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = DBContext.Set<T>();

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> where = t => t.ID == id;
    where = FilterDeleted(where);

    //Apply eager loading
    if (navigationProperties != null)
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

    item = dbQuery
        .Where(where)//Apply where clause
        .FirstOrDefault(); 

    return item;
}
```

I'm considering using [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-IncludeFilter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Include-Related-Entities-using-Where-Filter) to allow filtering on these navigation properties. However, I'm concerned about the complexity/inefficiency of the queries it generates so I want to try using it only on navigation properties that the built in `.Include` can't handle.

So first I need to determine what is a valid `Expression<Func<T, object>>` parameter for the `.Include` method. As far as I know it can only contain a property selector or a `.Select`. E.G.

```
t => t.Property;
t => t.Collection.Select(c => c.InnerCollection.Select(ic => ic.Property));
```

I've barely worked with Expression trees so I'm not sure how to begin taking this on. How would I go about analyzing an `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to determine if it contains anything other than these such as a `.Where` or `.OrderBy` or `.Take`?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/DbHelpers.cs#L260) is the method used by EF itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question :) I tried to create a little piece of code that suits your needs. Tested it with a number of possible inputs; if it's not working for something and someone points it out, I'm happy to work on it :)

See the comments for what's what.

```
static bool IsValid(LambdaExpression expression)
{
  // Expression is in the form of parameter => something
  // Body is the 'something' part
  var body = expression.Body;

  // MemberExpression are like p.Name, that's a valid body
  if (body is MemberExpression) 
     return true;

  // MethodCallExpression are like p.Select(...) or p.Where(...) or p.DoSomething(...)
  var methodCallExpression = body as MethodCallExpression;

  // If it's not a methodcall, it can't be a select, so it's invalid
  if (methodCallExpression == null)
      return false;

  // Method contains the actual MethodInfo
  var method = methodCallExpression.Method;

  // Select is a generic method, so if it's not generic, it can't be valid
  if (!method.IsGenericMethod)
      return false;

  // Get the actual, parameterless methoddefinition of Enumerable.Select
  // NOTE: This is ugly as hell, but AFAIK there's no better way 
  // just query for the method whose name is 'Select' and has two parameters where the second one has two generic arguments (that's the Func argument)
  var selectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                    .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Select) && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2);

  // If the method in the methodinfo is not the Select definition, it's not valid
  if (method.GetGenericMethodDefinition() != selectMethod)
      return false;

  // Otherwise the methodcall is in the form of p.Select(p=>'something else')
  // innerExpr gets the p=>'something else' part
  var innerExpr = methodCallExpression.Arguments[1];

  // If the expression really is a lambda expression, then recursively check the p=>'something else' part
  if (innerExpr is LambdaExpression lambda)
  {
    return IsValid(lambda);
  }
  else
  {
    // Otherwise it's invalid
    // NOTE: this is just in case, I'm not even sure if you can achieve this with regular C# code at compilation time
    return false;
  }                
}
```

Comment: I think this works. I went with a modified version of the [EntityFramework method](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/DbHelpers.cs#L260) that Ivan Stoev commented before you posted. It seems pretty much the same with a couple small differences. One is they just used the actual method name "Select" to check the call method. I assume theirs is faster but yours is more precise.  Thanks for your help!